# jQuery effect for resizing text

Tags: javascript, jquery

so, I'm trying to make two adjacent divs, such that on mouseover the div on the right is moving left and the div in left is resizing (getting tighter). The div on the left contains text that when div is getting tighter the words in the must go to next line to fit new size, and that's exactly what I want. but the problem is that when words go to next line they just disappear from line and appear in the next. I want them to move to the next line instead of disappearing and appearing, like this:
[image: without motion effect]
here is the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".SideMenu").mouseout(function() {

      $(".mainTitleDiv").animate({
        width: '900px',
      }, {
        queue: false,
      })


      $(".SideMenu").animate({
        right: '-500px',
      }, {
        queue: false,
      })
    });

  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".SideMenu").mouseover(function() {
      $(".mainTitleDiv").animate({
        width: '400px',
      }, {
        queue: false,
      })
      $(".SideMenu").animate({
        right: '0px',
      }, {
        queue: false,
      })
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Share the HTML code as well.

Comment: Also include the css, as that's the equally relevant part

Answer (score 0):

Here are options to achieve **Fitting Text** to a container

**USING CSS `vw`**

```
<h1>Fit Me</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One+SC');

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive;
  font-size: 25.5vw;
}
```

**USING jQUERY Library such [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)**

Here is a sample after including the library in your **HTML** file

```
jQuery("h1").fitText(0.38);
```

Here are link to other library

- [textFit](https://github.com/STRML/textFit)

Comment: that's a nice one, I tried it but it's not exactly what I meant.. I don't want to resize the font, I want it in the same size but I want it to move dynamically when div is getting tighter.